# A data structure “oracle” able to answer queries in O(1)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Let **V** be a vector of **n** elements, where each cell can contain one of **k** possible colors, that is

```
V[i] ∈ {c1. . . ,ck}
```

Design an algorithm that, given V, construct a "oracle" (a data structure) able to answer in O(1) to query of the following type:

*Given an index **i** and a color **c**, which is the index of the cell closer to i that contains the color c?*

The oracle construction algorithm must have complexity in O(kn), query algorithm in O(1).

**EDIT**

O(kn) concerns a time complexity, so there are no limits about the **additional memory**.

---

**My reasoning**

Given i and c, the query should return an index **j** with

```
V[j] = c
```

which minimizes | i - j |. If there's no cell that contains the color c, it must returns -1. So I guess that the two functions prototypes should be as following:

> ORACLE(array V, int k)
>
> QUERY(array O, int i, int c)

the array **O** is created by the oracle function in order to "save" the preprocessed values that will be subsequently extrapolated in O(1) by the function query. I'm stuck in this passage, because I can't understand how place values in order to get the right result. Any hints?

Comment: What is the maximum allowed size for O? Can it contain n * k elements?

Comment: @user2040251 O(kn) is declared as a **time** complexity, then I believe that O can also be a matrix.

Comment: Very broadly: you could construct k one-dimensional [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), one for each color. I suspect making one diagram is O(n) time, so making k of them should take O(kn) time. Then the oracle lookup is O(1) as desired.

Comment: @Kevin Nice and interesting hint, I didn't even know this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, your oracle should probably be an NxK array with the answer for every index and every color stored as an integer index that gives the index closes to the query index that has the query color. Initialize your oracle array to all -1. Then go through your array V first forward and then backards. When you go through forward, simply keep track of the last index in V where you have seen color k for each color k (with -1 if you haven't seen the color yet), and then as you proceed through V in forward order, if you are at index i then the answer for the oracle for color j is the last index where you saw color j. Then go through the array V backwards, and keep track of the last time you saw each color. When you are at position j in the array V, check to see what the index for the closest cell of each color was when you went forward, and if the index for the last cell when you saw a color when you are going backwards is closer, then over-write the oracle cell with the closer index. After you go through the array both forwards and backwards, you will have the oracle fully constructed and ready to query in O(1) time.